# How do I ssh into a new virtual machine?

Tags: centos, rhel, virtual-machine

<sup>**note by derobert:** problem was resolved in chat, starting around http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24666451#24666451 if someone wants to write up an answer. Turns out the bridge wasn't set up; most of that chat is figuring out how to do it with nmcli. **end note.**</sup>

I am using `virt-install` to install a minimal, no-gui centos 7 virtual machine on a minimal, no-gui centos 7 host server.  The vm has been created and launched within the server host, and I am able to login to the virtual machine as root using the keyboard attached to the server.  **But how do I `ssh` into the virtual machine from a different computer on my network?**

---

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

---

I started by setting up bridge networking on the host os as follows:

```
# nmcli con add type bridge ifname br0
```

Then I created the VM from the host as follows:

```
# systemctl start libvirtd.service
# virt-install \
   --name=public-centos7 \
   --disk path=/home/publicvm/some.img,size=10 \
   --graphics none --vcpus=2 --memory=2048 \
   --location /var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso \
   --network bridge=br0 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7.0 \
   --extra-args console=ttyS0
```

In the resulting console dialog, I set up networking as follows:

```
Device configuration

 1) IPv4 address or "dhcp" for DHCP
    ip.of.new.vm
 2) IPv4 netmask
    255.255.255.0
 3) IPv4 gateway
    ip.of.server
 4) IPv6 address or "auto" for automatic, "dhcp" for DHCP, "ignore" to turn off
    auto
 5) IPv6 default gateway
 6) Nameservers (comma separated)
    8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8
 7) [x] Connect automatically after reboot
 8) [x] Apply configuration in installer
```

I then completed the installation process successfully.  This launched CentOS 7 within the virtual machine and enabled me to log in as root using the password that I set in the installation process.  **But I am not yet able to successfully `ssh root@ip.of.new.vm` from another computer on the network.**  Attempts to ssh from another pc on the network just time out without connecting.

**What changes do I need to make in order to be able to `ssh` into the resulting virtual machine, using its own dedicated ip address that is different from the host's ip address.**  This is on a local network, so I can assign an ip address on a moment's notice.

As per @garethTheRed's comment, the result of `ip route` at the host is:

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.8  metric 100
```

And the result of `ip route` at the guest is:

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev etho0 proto static metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.6 metric 100
```

Comment: @derobert Since you did all the work, you should write up the answer. :-)