# use mutt to send email through specific port on CentOS 7

Tags: scripting, email, mutt

What specific syntax do I use to get mutt to send an email through port 587 on a CentOS 7 server?

For example, the sender is `me@mydomain.com`, the recipient is `someone.else@someotherdomain.com`, the subject is `This is the subject`, and the message body is `This is the message body.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `~/.muttrc` or `~/.mutt/muttrc`, files which may be or may not be reside in your home directory, you can add the following lines:

```
set smtp_url="smtp://yourusername@smtp.example.com:587/"
set smtp_pass="insertyourpasswordhere"
```

This only works if the smtp option is enabled during compilation.

If neither of these files are in your home directory, you should create one of them first. If you have one of them, don't remove content that may be already there. Just make sure that the lines mentioned above contain the correct. Insert your own mailaddress and password of course.

The general method to send a mail with Mutt is like

```
echo "This is the message body" | mutt -s "This is the subject" someone.else@someotherdomain.com
```

or you can create a textfile with your message body ( let's say /tmp/message.txt) and do this

```
mutt -s "This is the subject" someone.else@someotherdomain.com < /tmp/message.txt
```

If you want to set sender details add the following to muttrc as mentioned above:

```
set from = "Enteryouremailaddresshere"<br>
set realname = "Yourname"
```

Mutt commands mentioned here should be one a single line.

Comment: Thank you.  However, your response assumes a level of familiarity that would cause a person not to need to ask the question in the first place.  Can you please re-state your response in language that gives step by step instructions for a newbie who might do a google search on this topic?

Comment: Yes sure, I'll try editing it. Judging by your reputation I thought you were a power user, but of course we deal with other users here too.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for giving the `echo` and `mutt` commands in cut and paste format.

Comment: Where exactly do I find or place the `muttrc` file?  When I type `sudo find / -name "*muttrc"`, the only result is:  `/usr/share/doc/mutt-1.5.21/sample.muttrc`.  When I try `sudo nano /usr/share/doc/mutt-1.5.21/sample.muttrc`, the bottom of the file says `source ~/.muttrc-local`, but then `find / -name ".muttrc-local"` does not produce any results.  Do you suggest that I make a new file called `~/.muttrc` or `~/.mutt/muttrc`?  If so, does the new file go in the root `/` directory?  Or do I make a separate copy of the new file in each `/home/username` directory?

Comment: I am able to send an email from any given username by ssh-ing into that username's CentOS account and typing `echo "This is the message body" | mutt -s "This is the subject" someone.else@someotherdomain.com` in the terminal.  The message is received by `someone.else@someotherdomain.com`, but I still do not have any way of confirming that the message was sent out using 587 or any other given port because I have not been able to view the `muttrc` file or any other output indicating the port number.

Comment: Mail is normally sent out using port 25 so if you didn't set the lines to use port 587 the mail is sent out using port 25. With regard to the question about muttrc you need to know that ~/ is short for /home/yourusername/, so if you create /home/yourusername/.muttrc, you have the correct file (note there's a dot before muttrc, if you create /home/yourusername/.mutt/muttrc it should work too (note now there's a dot before mutt but no dot before muttrc.